# short circuit creator

Tags: short-circuit

Apologies if I'm very naive in this my first post

We are looking for some kind of "short-circuit creator" device for our house; basically our idea is to plug this device on the AC mains and then create a short-circuit, just to test if the box with the flips are flipping (sorry, don't know the technical name!)

Not sure if you can help us? what kind of device do we need to buy in order to create a controlled and safe short-circuit on our house?

Comment: A piece of wire? (don't do this) Why not just an overload instead of a short? Would be somewhat the same test and much safer.

Comment: What if the box with the flips are not flipping and then your walls catch fire instead? (by the way they are called **circuit breakers** or just **breakers** for short)

Comment: That’s kind of like shooting yourself in the chest to see if your bullet proof vest is working.

Comment: @BlairFonville: Which is exactly what the guy who invented the first flexible bullet proof vest did.  Nobody believed an pile of cloth would stop a bullet, so he proved it.

Comment: use a plug pigtail and a switch. be careful.

Comment: If you make one as specified above, disconnect all the devices with sensitive electronics - I had a kettle that caused the circuit breaker to go and the surge damaged the inductiin hob...

Comment: a person that does not know the name for a breaker panel should stay away from working with line power

Comment: Think of it this way: if your circuit breakers are working, you gain nothing from testing them. If they aren't, instead of starting a fire in the unlikely even of a faulty appliance, you will start a fire right now with near-100% probability.

Answer (score 7):

There is no reason to test circuit breakers. Manufacturers and/or independent testing laboratories do extensive testing to assure that they they always trip at or below the design tripping current. If you suspect that a circuit breaker is tripping when it shouldn't, replace it. If a circuit breaker goes bad, that is the way if is supposed to go bad, tripping when it shouldn't trip.

If you want to experience a circuit breaker tripping, load up the circuit by plugging in enough loads to trip it as suggested in the answer by Tony Stewart. If it is instructive, it is ok to do, but there is no reason to test your circuit breakers. You should probably not intentionally create a short circuit for any reason.

Although, circuit breakers are designed to be capable of being reset and function correctly after a short circuit, the number one requirement is to trip when they should. They are not necessarily guaranteed to survive ay specific number of trips.

Comment: You could also buy a circuit breaker and test it on a low-voltage circuit. A typical lab PSU can output 30 amps at low voltage, which will trip a 20A or 15A breaker without any real danger

Answer (score 6):

Charles is correct for regular circuit breakers, but there is also a safer type known as GFCI in the US, RCD in the UK, and these should be tested periodically.

They can be identified because they have a button labelled "T" or "Test" on them. To test them, don't short circuit the power, just press that button.

Answer (score 3):

Do not test the little flippy thingy (called a *circuit breaker*) with a short.

Stop and actually *think* about it.  If the point of the test is to discover whether the thing trips as it's supposed to, what's supposed to happen if it doesn't trip?  The current in the wires inside your walls will go very high.  This heats the wires to unsafe levels, which can start a fire inside the walls, which burns your house down.  That is precisely what the circuit breaker is supposed to prevent.

In reality, it is very very unlikely that you will find a breaker that won't trip.  These things are safety devices, providing the last line of defense when everything else has already messed up and would otherwise burn your house down.  Much testing and certification go into their design and manufacture, and they are designed to fail safe.

If you really want to verify that a particular breaker is working, load that circuit with only a little more current than the breaker is rated for.  In theory, the breaker should trip at the rated current.  I'd try to draw maybe 10% more just to remove any doubt.

The way to get to a particular current is to plug in enough devices that add up to the target current.  The easiest is probably a bank of old LEBs (light emitting bulbs).  They can safely dissipate their rated power, and you can see immediately when the breaker trips.  A bunch of lights in parallel would do it.

Most appliances are rated for the power they draw, not the current, but breakers trip according to current.  To get the current, divide the power by the line voltage.  For example, a bank of lights adding up to 500 W with 115 V line will draw (500 W)/(115 V) = 4.4 A.

However, there is probably some slop in the wattage spec, and it is probably worst case at highest line voltage.  The wattage spec of devices isn't meant to be something calibrated for testing circuit breakers with.  It's meant to be a maximum spec you can rely on the device never exceeding.

To test a circuit breaker properly, you need to measure the line voltage, then use a calibrated resistance to draw a known amount of current.  This is really beyond anyone who has to ask here and refers to breakers as the "flip" things.  Either just trust your breakers, like everyone else, or get a electrician to test them properly and safely.

By trying to do this yourself, you have a higher chance of electrocuting yourself or burning your house down than to get any useful information.  Just don't.

Answer (score 2):

You are far better off using a heater or two hair driers or toaster and kettle to test how fast it will trip a 10A 15A or 20A breaker based on load/rating ratio.

Answer (score 2):

**Don't do that.**

Here in the UK, there's an assumption that the worst case short-circuit current on a small installation will not exceed 16kA.  That's sixteen thousand amps.  It may be different in other countries, but will still be in the kiloamps range.

It's anyone's guess what will happen to the switch you're using to create the short circuit.

If your consumer unit (fuse box) is properly designed, it should not explode, but the breakers affected may never work again.  If your consumer unit doesn't break the circuit very quickly, then your supplier's fuse will blow instead.  There's every chance that you could end up calling the supplier to fit a new fuse, and an electrician to replace the consumer unit you were trying to test.

Answer (score 0):

You can buy or rent an installation tester. For example an Fluke 1663.
This can test various aspects of you electrical installation.

For example, it can test GFCI (RCD) trip thresholds and time by controllerd leaking current to earth.

It cannot test MCB (miniature circuit breaker) thermal/magnetic threshold and time.
It is dangerous to test thermal magnetic circuit breakers. Since a fault condition *should* trip the upstream circuit breaker or fuse. The tester might not be suitable for such rating.

You can test the thermal circuit breaker mode by overloading it by 2x nominal.
You can test the magnetic circuit breaker mode by a short or overloading with at least 10 times nominal.
Any attempts with relays will result in welded contacts or exploded relays.

The way these devices are normally tested is with a current transformer. This way you have control over the test current and it is limited to the saturation of the transformer. Switching is done at the primary side.

But I suggest you hire an certified electrician to inspect your installation.